OpenFDA: API retrieval limits
good afternoon.
I am building an application using the OpenFDA to pull medical device adverse events data. It seems that the limit to pull data in one api call is 25000 records, can this be confirmed? We sometimes pull data for mutiple manufactures like Medtronic, Boston scientific, Abbott, and the pull can exceed 25000 records, your help and feedback is appreciated.
Thank you

yes, that limit is correct. If you need more data, please narrow down your query, and execute multiple queries. Thank you!
